# relational database pass values (confused)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, relational-database

I am a beginner and try to improve myself with my own project. I have worked only with small databases and it was fine. But now, I want to try some relationships and indexing, but struggle a bit.

I work with PHP(Laravel) and MySQL

Here is my database design:
[image]

Normaly, if you got a post on a blog, you have got an user id related to the user. That is what I understand.

But in my example I have got a multi-form, where I user add a marker(lat,lng), a adress and some details in this example for sport. I store step for step in a session.

**Now here is my problem, if I store first a adress in the database, then add a marker related to the user id(m_user_id) and adress id(m_adress_id), how do I get the right id from the adresses table?**

The user id I could find in the session, when the user is logged in, but how about the adress id? If I put the user id in the adresses table and the user post more than once, how to select the right one?

I am confused, ****!!! Need more sleep

Sorry, for my poor english. I hope, you get my confusion. :)

Comment: Usually you will give the user an option to select his "default" address if there are more than one.

Comment: *"Need more sleep"* - Right, do. You will achieve more if you had a good night's sleep. That, is one of coders' best friend.

Comment: the adress is for a marker. and you can post more than one marker/posts